# Extending the `events.xml` file

Tags: xml, magento2.2.4

I'm trying to disable the default UrlRewrite event observers in the `magento-catalog-url-rewrite` Module. I have extended the file under `app/code/xyz/MagentoCatalogUrlRewrite/etc/events.xml`, set the option `disabled=true` in the relevant observers but the events still fire. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Check this post, quite similar to your requirements https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/167998/how-to-override-observers-in-magento-2?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked was creating **around plugin**for every observer responsible for the default *url_rewrite* in magento that returns $subject as @Amit Bera had pointed out. You will have to replace the class responsible for listening for the event to the plugin class you have defined in **events.xml**.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest rewriting the observer class which is called at `magento-catalog-url-rewrite`''s events,xml.

Suppose,`Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Observer\CategoryUrlPathAutogeneratorObserver` class.

In this case, you have to create **around plugin**  on `execute()` method, and and  donot proceed.

```
namespace Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Observer;

class CategoryUrlPathAutogeneratorObserverPlugin
{
    public function aroundExecute(\Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Observer\CategoryUrlPathAutogeneratorObserver $subject, callable $proceed)
    {
        return $subject;
    }
}
```

Comment: it is user call, they can override  method by class override  the use `execute` .if you want to use plugin  my solution

Comment: this method doesn't work