# Override Observer In Magento2

Tags: magento2

I have an extension foomen and there is observer exsist i want to rewrite that observer how can i do that?.

Comment: was it installed via composer?

Comment: no my extension in code folder

Comment: its email attachment module

Comment: <event name="fooman_emailattachments_before_send_invoice">
        <observer name="fooman_emailattachments_before_send_invoice_observer"
                  instance="Fooman\EmailAttachments\Observer\BeforeSendInvoiceObserver"/>
    </event>

Comment: this is the event in module i want rewrite this one

Answer (score 1):

In you custom module `app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml` add observer override entry

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Fooman\ModuleName\Observer\ObserverName" type="Vendor\Module\Observer\ObserverName" />
</config>
```

Now copy observer file from **Fooman** into your module `app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer` and change `namespace` of file

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;
```

Rest will be same

```
Run di compile and static deploy at the end
php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento setup:di:compile
php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

For reference, see this: [How to override observers in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/167998/how-to-override-observers-in-magento-2)